# how to insert data in one to many relationship in spring jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new in Spring. I want to insert the data into the `AUDIT` table. There is a one-two-many relationship between `USER` and `AUDIT` tables.

For every login and logout data should be inserted into the `AUDIT` table. How can I do that?

The user entity:

```
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="USERID")
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String email;

    private Long phone;

    private String password;

    private int OTP;

    private boolean activation_flag;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="USERID")
    private Set<Audit> audit;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ADDRESSID")
    private Address address;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "USER_AUTHORITY",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USERID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "AUTHORITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private List<Authority> authorities;
```

The audit entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AUDIT")
public class Audit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="AUDITID")
    private long auditid;

    @Column(name="GEOLOCATION")
    private String geolocation;

    @Column(name="ACTION")
    private String action;

    @Column(name="DATETIME")
    private Date datetime;

    @Column(name="DEVICEID")
    private long deviceid;

    @Column(name="ACTIONSUCCESS_FAIL")
    private boolean actionsuccess_fail;

    @Column(name="JWT_TOKEN")
    @Type(type="text")
    private String JWT_token;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
```

The audit repository:

```
public interface AuditRepository extends JpaRepository<Audit, Long> {
}
```

The user repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
    User findByEmail(String email);
    User findByPhone(Long phone);
    User findById(Long id);

}
```

Comment: I've improved formatting (for better readability and hopefully more answers)

Comment: Thomas Fritsch   thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add the audit to the user you want the audit associated with, then save.

Comment: Thanku letsBeFrank..can you please tell me how can I insert data in one to many relationships..

Comment: user.getAudits().add(newAudit);  then userRepository.save(user);

Comment: any one have answer i want to add through REST api